# Why am I getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when watching for change to parent scope variable (filtered ng-repeat array)?

Tags: angularjs

My problem is I want to watch for changes to a filtered array created with ng-repeat, for that I'm referencing to the parent scope since I've learned ng-repeat creates its own scope, and while watching the array with $scope.$watch actually works (it accurately detects changes to the array), I get multiple console log errors saying: ***angular.js:12520 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.***
Anyone have any inputs to what I can do to solve the problem?

HTML: 
`<div class="module-card" ng-repeat="module in ($parent.filteredModules = (modules | released : true | moduleFilter : allFilters | unique: 'name' | orderBy : sortFunc : orderedAsc | limitTo : limitResults)) track by $index">`

JS:

```
$scope.$watch('filteredModules', function(newVal, oldVal){
   console.log(newVal, oldVal);
}, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using $scope.$watchCollection instead.. If anyone bumps into the same problem.